# Can someone explain strict mass assignment in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm just getting up to speed with Rails 3.2, and when I use create or update_attributes, I always seem to get mass assignment errors.  Is this normal?  How should I be creating and updating records?

Comment: are you using nested resources?

Comment: Do you mean am I assigning attributes through associations (i.e. blongs_to), then yes.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Michael Hartl wrote on this topic: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3781233

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add the attributes you want to set via massassignment to the whitelist in the model `attr_accessible :my_attribute`

allowing to set related nested model-attributes through the same form, you have to set an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for this model and add the attributes to the whitelist `attr_accessible :$RELATED_MODEL_attributes`

read those links.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Ok, I see. So by default, mass assignment is restricted, and this is normal behavior?

Comment: No if you don't set `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` all attributes are accessible and can be massassigned. So default ist all open... if you set either on of them you create a white/blacklist then... if you want to assigen nested attributes though. you have to add them to the whitelist, otherwise you get the massassignment error you see. so you're forced to set `attr_accessible` in this case...

Comment: Seems the Michael Hartle post referenced above contradicts you a bit in that by default, at least in 3.2.3, mass assignment is restricted unless you whitelist with attr_accessible.

Comment: It used to be like this in 3.2.0. Which version are you using? BUt regardless the version, using whitelists was always good practice.

Comment: One of the main point of Rails 3.2.3 was the change of requiring `attr_accessible` by default for new apps (according to the [release notes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/30/ann-rails-3-2-3-has-been-released/)). This does not affect existing apps, it just strengthens the view that mass-assignment must be carefully configured to be secure.